# Getting variables from string with regular expressions

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

i'm getting nuts with an regular expression. I have a string like this:

```
%closed% closed (%closed_percent%\%), %open% open (%open_percent%\%)
```

What I need is a regular expression that matches the following:

```
%closed%
%closed_percent%
%open%
%open_percent%
```

but not the two \%

At the moment I use:

```
\%([^\%]+)\%
```

that gives me:

```
%closed%
%closed_percent%
%), %
% open (%
...
```

Anyone can help me with that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simple way:

```
%\w+%
```

Matches: `%foo%`

Allows (multiple) backslash escapes:

```
(?<!\\)(?:\\.)*%(\w+)%
```

Matches only `bar` in: `\%foo% \\%bar% \\\%baz%`

...and this allows escapes inside of it too:

```
(?<!\\)(?:\\.)*%((?:[^\\%\s]+|\\.)+)%
```

Matches: `%foo\%bar%`

Use the value of the first capturing group with the last two expressions.

Comment: Nice trick. I had to change `[^\%\s]` to `[^\\%\s]` to get it to work - you want a literal backslash, most flavors will see `\%` and ignore the backslash, as if you wrote `%`. By the way, why are everyone escaping the present sign? Does it mean anything in any flavor?

Comment: @Kobi, in Perl it's a sign for a hash variable, which (I guess) could get interpolated. You have nice built in hashes like `%+ %-`. Same goes for `@`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
\%([^(\\\%)]+?)\%
```

matches

```
%closed%
%closed_percent%
%open%
%open_percent%
```

for me.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming no restrictions on what can be in the percent wrapped tokens (including escaped characters), and what characters can be escaped (so backslashes can also be escaped: `\\%token%` should be valid),
 here's a pattern you can use to skip over escaped characters:

```
\\.|(%([^%\\]|\\.)+%)
```

This will capture the percent-wrapped tokens, and will capture them in the first group (`$1`). Escaped characters will also be matched (it's a nice trick to skip over them), but using PHP it is very easy to get just the relevant tokens:

```
preg_match_all('/\\\\.|(%([^%\\\\]|\\\\.)+%)/', $str, $matches, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
$matches = array_filter($matches[1]);
```

Working example: http://ideone.com/dziCB

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
~\%\w+\%~
```

So, allow only a-z A-Z and _ in your selection.

```
$str = "%closed% closed (%closed_percent%\%), %open% open (%open_percent%\%)";

preg_match_all("~\%\w+\%~", $str, $matches);
```

`$matches` now contains:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
    (
        [0] => %closed%
        [1] => %closed_percent%
        [2] => %open%
        [3] => %open_percent%
    )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Add negative lookbehinds for the backslashes! That way `\%` is ignored, as intended.

```
(?<!\\)\%([^\%]+)(?<!\\)\%
```

Matches

> %closed%
>
> %closed_percent%
>
> %open%
>
> %open_percent%